# Setup FeignClient or Ribbon for only one method

Tags: java

I use Feign in our application and setup the `readTimeOut = 30000`, but there are some methods, that will call other application to get a lot of data, so it will spend more time, how can I setup `readTimeOut` for these methods?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this page?:

https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/issues/590

Here you can find an example where one Feign user uses timeouts in the initialization of the `ConfigurationManager`:

```
ConfigurationManager.getConfigInstance()
                .setProperty("hystrix.command.PhotoService#getToken(String,String,String).execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds", 7000);
 return Feign.builder()
                .decoder(new GsonDecoder())
                .encoder(new GsonEncoder())
                .options(new Request.Options(config.getConnectTimeoutMillis(), config.getReadTimeoutMillis()))
                .target(PhotoService.class, baseUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom configuration for particular FeignClien

More details here : 
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html#spring-cloud-feign-overriding-defaults

For example:

```
@FeignClient(name = "stores", configuration = FooConfiguration.class)
public interface StoreClient {
 //..
}
```

and create a bean with custom configuration (`FooConfiguration.class`)

Comment: thank you for you reply ! but by this way, apllication can only setup one method ,if there are ten methods, their timeout are diffrent ,how to setup?